# context suggestor behaving erratically for alphanumeric text search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get the results based on the following query string "sp5".
But what I get are those strings which starts with sp but have any number after them.

I get output as sp1210, sp1211, sp1234 etc. Why is elasticsearch not performing strict prefix search to return only those strings which start with "sp5"?
Is there a way I could make elastic search do strict check in case of alphanumeric text search?

```
GET address_staging/_search
{
"suggest":{
"suggestions":{
  "text": "sp5",
  "completion":{
    "field":"name_aliases_suggest",
    "size":20,
    "contexts":{
      "company_id":["smithfield-foods"]
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use analyser: "keyword" , simple_analyser: "keyword". The above issue was caused when I used analyser: "simple" , simple_analyser: "simple".